# Polyfit (MATLAB) polynomial not matching polynomial generated through Excel (LINEST)

Tags: excel, matlab

I would have expected polynomial weights generated through LINEST(excel) and POLYFIT(matlab) would give the same result. Even though the predicted y-values are similar, the polynomial weights do not match.

MATLAB

```
[p, s, mu] = POLYFIT(X, Y, 3);
```

EXCEL

```
LINEST(D2:D52, A2:C52, TRUE, TRUE)
%D2-D52 contains observed y-values and A2-C52 contains x,x^2 and x^3
```

Is my expectation flawed in any sense? Please advise

Comment: It might be related to total-least squares method vs least squares - the distance measure is different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The presence of the `mu` parameter is more than likely the culprit.
The `mu` output tells MATLAB to adjust the `x` values to improve the fitting algorithm's numerical properties ([`polyfit` documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/polyfit.html#description)).
This shift-and-scale weights that fit this normalized data `x_hat` are different from the unscaled version `x`.

Therefore, the MATLAB input

```
p = polyfit(x,y,3); 
% or [p,S] = polyfit(x,y,3); if you want stats
```

and

```
=LINEST(D2:D52, A2:C52, TRUE, TRUE)
```

should be the same.